# PHP: passing parameters in the URL dynamically

Tags: php

I want to display data in database in table form. I wrote the following code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['EmpID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['EmpName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Designation'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Salary'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='upasg3.php?empid='". $row['EmpID'] .">Edit</a ></td>";
echo "<td><a href='upasg3.php?empid='". $row['EmpID'] .">Delete</a ></td>"; 
echo "</tr>";
}
```

But i dont get the value of $row['EmpID'] concatenated with the value of href. It redirects to the upasg3.php with empid= blank.
how to fix this? Please help

Comment: Is this line blank as well: `echo "<td>" . $row['EmpID'] . "</td>";` ?

Comment: @user1400633 accept the correct answer please.

Answer (score 4):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['EmpID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['EmpName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Designation'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Salary'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='upasg3.php?empid=". $row['EmpID'] ."'>Edit</a ></td>";
echo "<td><a href='upasg3.php?empid=". $row['EmpID'] ."'>Delete</a ></td>"; 
echo "</tr>";
}
```

quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the single quotes after empid=

And putting them here like this:

```
echo "<td><a href='upasg3.php?empid=". $row['EmpID'] ."'>Edit</a ></td>";
echo "<td><a href='upasg3.php?empid=". $row['EmpID'] ."'>Delete</a ></td>";
```

This will give you an output like:

```
<a href='upasg3.php?empid=100'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
echo "<td><a href='upasg3.php?empid=". $row['EmpID']."'>Edit</a ></td>";
                                    ^                 ^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
 <td>ID</td>
<td>NAME</td>
<td>Designation</td>
<td>Salary</td>
<td>Edit</td>
  <td>Delete</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><?=$row['EmpID']?></td>
<td><?=$row['EmpName']?></td>
<td><?=$row['Designation']?></td>
<td><?=$row['Salary']?></td>
<td><a href="upasg3.php?empid=<?=$row['EmpID']?>">Edit</a></td>
 <td><a href="upasg3.php?empid=<?=$row['EmpID']?>">Delete</a></td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
echo "<td><a href='upasg3.php?empid=". $row['EmpID'] ."'>Edit</a ></td>";
echo "<td><a href='upasg3.php?empid=". $row['EmpID'] ."'>Delete</a ></td>";
```

Your quotes were in wrong place.